# Обособление обстоятельства

Tags: пунктуация

> И день и ночь по снеговой пустыне, спешу к вам, голову сломя.

Почему после "пустыне" стоит запятая?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это зафиксированная в нескольких изданиях опечатка; в предложении вообще не должно быть никаких знаков - ничего они в нём не забыли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Розенталь: [§94. Обособленные обстоятельства](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm) - примечание б) к пункту 1.

> *И день и ночь по снеговой пустыне спешу к вам голову сломя* (Грибоедов)

Нашла издание 1866 года:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и Софью там не обзывают Софией, и запрашиваемой запятой нет (есть иные пунктуационные несовременности),

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и дикая запятая в "не образумлюсь, виноват, и слушаю, не понимаю" исчезла, вернув тексту законное авторское тире!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Классный ответ, очень познавательный, и так красиво оформлен.  Как хорошо Вы знаете тексты!

Comment: Спасибо на добром слове! ))) Текстов я не знаю - я чувствую знаки (препинания). Вот это "слушаю - не понимаю" мне запомнилось на слух из фильма "Дом, в котором я живу" (Галя - Жанна Болотова).

Comment: Вот если бы можно было всех научить чувствовать знаки. Но это, наверное, в будущем, а  пока приходится писать по правилам.